# PrimeNG TreeSelect - how to expand node on click, if it has children?

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm using PrimeNG angular [TreeSelect](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v15-lts/treeselect) component, and I want to make only nodes that do not have children selectable.

My node:

```
export interface ICategorySelectListDto {
    id: number;
    label: string;
    children: CategorySelectListDto[] | undefined;
}
```

I could use [CascadeSelect](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v15-lts/cascadeselect) component but I have different depth of tree branches.